# Problem proving the Fresnel integral

Tags: complex-analysis, fresnel-integrals

I have shown that

$$\int^\infty_0 e^{ix^2}dx = \dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2},$$

using contour integration on $f(z) = e^{iz^2}$. But since

$$\int^\infty_0 e^{ix^2}dx = \int^\infty_0 (\cos x^2+ i \sin x^2) dx = \dfrac{\sqrt\pi}{2},  $$
I would have thought equating the imaginary and real parts would do the trick. But this just gives wrong answers. What's wrong here?

Comment: Your first result is not correct. It should be $\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, you're right. I made a dumb mistake. This fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome !